# how to set useBodyEncodingForURI="true" in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat6

I use spring boot to do a WEB project. I want to modify tomcat default allocation. If it is a spring project, I can modify it in server.xml, but it is spring boot. How can I set it?

Answer (score 2):

You should create the following JavaConfig Class.

```
@Bean
EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return (containerFactory) -> {
        if (containerFactory instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
            TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatContainerFactory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) containerFactory;
            tomcatContainerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((connector) -> {
                connector.setUseBodyEncodingForURI(true);
            });
        }
    };
}
```